# Android GraphicBuffer with pixel format HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YV12

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, egl

I try to create Android GraphicBuffer with this instruction

new GraphicBuffer(160, 98, HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YV12, GraphicBuffer::USAGE_HW_TEXTURE |
        GraphicBuffer::USAGE_SW_WRITE_RARELY)

It works well on my Android 4.0 device Huawei Mediapad, but not on Android 2.3 HTC Desire. 
That is i get error:

05-28 16:53:15.994: W/GraphicBufferAllocator(3765): alloc(160, 98, 842094169, 00000120, ...) failed -22 (Invalid argument)

If I'd change pixel format from HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YV12 to HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB_565 then it will work well on both my devices. I suppose that Android 2.3 hasn't support for YV12
But I need YUV pixel's format in any case.

Answer (score 0):

if you need YUV then use NV21 which is HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YCrCb_420_SP, and is supported by all API levels.

Though YV12 was introduced in API level 9, it is only guaranteed to be supported in all devices starting from API 12.